# How to increase value of sharedpreferences

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences

on click button i get total alarm values and increase it ++ but it gave an error. i guess i try to create same sharedpreferences every time when i click the button. All i need to do is when click the button just create a sharedpref. and put a variable and every click increase it one by one.

```
SharedPreferences alarmlar = getSharedPreferences("alarmlar", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int kayitli_alarm = alarmlar.getInt("toplam_alarm", 0);
int toplam_alarm = kayitli_alarm++;
SharedPreferences.Editor alarm_arttir = alarmlar.edit();
alarm_arttir.putString("toplam_alarm", Integer.toString(toplam_alarm));
alarm_arttir.commit();
```

Comment: So what is the error then?

Comment: it works only first click.

Comment: That isn't an error message

Comment: that means doesn't work every click.

Comment: I can create sharedpref. and value is 0 i mean i cant increase that value every click.

Comment: And what if you use `apply` instead of `commit`?

Comment: Is it try to create sharedpref. every click.

Comment: I doesn't create a new one every click... That's not how that method works. The first string is the filename. It only creates one until you manually clear the application data

Comment: Ok, i got it so why i can't increase that value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106600/discussion-between-user2265473-and-cricket-007).

Comment: Please change `commit()` to `apply()` to see if that works

Comment: i change it but app is unfortunately stopped.

Comment: I'm trying this answer now i will write the result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530196/adding-to-sharedpreference-value-with-multiple-onclicklistener?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: it works but if i close app and reopen it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing `String` value and fetching it as `int`. Use below line for storing value

```
alarm_arttir.putInt("toplam_alarm", toplam_alarm);
```

First time it will work, as it will not have any values and it will take default value.

Comment: That's what i am looking. Sorry already reached today's vote limit.

Comment: @MD thanks, your comment is enough for users like us, who are new to android :)

Comment: The question has been updated, so this answer is no longer correct

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i know, now if someone else will give answer, OP will again update question, I think that's not the correct way to ask question.

Comment: Perhaps, or maybe since `commit()` happens asynchronously, then OP is not noticing the change.